# Table of Contents from André Weil's Edition of Kummer's papers

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I would be very grateful if someone could provide me with the table of contents of Volume 1 (pertaining Number Theory) of *Andre Weil*'s edition of *Ernst Kummer*'s papers, published by *Springer Verlag* in *1975*. I need the reference to some papers there for bibliographic quotation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going to cite a paper, shouldn't you look at it and not rely on secondary citations?

Answer (score 0):

I will update my answer with the table of contents when I find them.

But I have the link to the references which you want: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183539459#references

The below references have been taken from that link.

References

1. H. M. Edwards, The background of Kummer's proof of Fermat's last theorem for regular primes, Arch. History Exact Sci. 14 (1975), no. 3, 219-236.
   Zentralblatt MATH: 0323.01022
   Mathematical Reviews (MathSciNet): MR472364
   Digital Object Identifier: doi: 10.1007/BF00327448
2. G. Eisenstein, Mathematische Werke, Chelsea, New York, 1975.
   Zentralblatt MATH: 0339.01018
3. C. G. J. Jacobi, Gesammelte Werke, Reimer, Berlin, 1890.
4. L. Lewin, Dilogarithms and associated functions, Macdonald, London, 1958. MR 21 #4264.
   Zentralblatt MATH: 0083.35904
   Mathematical Reviews (MathSciNet): MR105524
5. J. M. Masley and H. L. Montgomery, Cyclotomic fields with unique factorization (to appear).
   Zentralblatt MATH: 0335.12013
   Mathematical Reviews (MathSciNet): MR429824
6. K. Iwasawa, A class number formula for cyclotomic fields, Ann. of Math. (2) 76 (1962), 171-179. MR 27 #4806.
   Zentralblatt MATH: 0125.02003
   Mathematical Reviews (MathSciNet): MR154862
   Digital Object Identifier: doi: 10.2307/1970270
7. K. Iwasawa, On p-adic L functions, Ann. of Math. (2) 89 (1969), 198-205. MR 42 #4522.
   Zentralblatt MATH: 0186.09201
   Mathematical Reviews (MathSciNet): MR269627
   Digital Object Identifier: doi: 10.2307/1970817
8. L. Stickelberger, Über eine Verallgemeinerung der Kreistheilung, Math. Ann. 37 (1890), 321-367.
   Mathematical Reviews (MathSciNet): MR1510649
   Digital Object Identifier: doi: 10.1007/BF01721360
9. K. Uchida, Class numbers of imaginary abelian number fields. III, Tôhoku Math. J. (to appear). Published papers of Kummer referred to, with dates of publication: (and their numbers in Lampe's bibliography (K 21-28)):
   Zentralblatt MATH: 0241.12002
   Mathematical Reviews (MathSciNet): MR374092
10. K. Uchida, De numeris complexis, qui radicibus unitatis et numeris integris realibus constant, 1844 (republished, 1847), L (ampe) 20.
11. K. Uchida, Über die Divisoren gewisser Formen der Zahlen, welche aus der Theorie der Kreistheilung entstehen, 1846, L 23.
12. K. Uchida, Beweis des Fermat'schen Satzes der Unmöglichkeit von xλ + yλ = zλ für eine unendliche Anzahl Primzahlen λ, 1847, L 24.
13. K. Uchida, Über eine allgemeine Eigenschaft der rationalen Entwickelungscoefficienten einer bestimmten Gattung analytischer Functionen, 1851, L 38.
14. K. Uchida, Mémoire sur la théorie des nombres complexes composés de racines de l'unité et de nombres entiers, 1851, L 39.
15. K. Uchida, Über die Irregularität von Determinanten, 1853. Not in Lampe's bibliography!
16. K. Uchida, Einige Sätze über die aus den Wurzeln der Gleichung aλ = 1 gebildeten complexen Zahlen, für den Fall, dass die Klassenzahl durch λ theilbar ist, nebst Anwendung derselben auf einen weiteren Beweis des letzten Fermat'schen Lehrsatzes, 1857, L 45.

Comment: Thanks, but those are references fro other authors working on Kummer. What I am searching for ist the list of articles by Kummer (with their page reference) edited by Weil in his first Volumen of Collected Papers.

Comment: Okay; I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find it; looks like it's only in libraries around the world... Shall I delete the answer? @JavierArias

Comment: No, just keep it here.